# Mutate running variable in loop Rust

Tags: rust

I have a for loop in Rust and in a condition that is satisfied I want to rerun a part of the loop. For example:

```
for mut n in 0..vector.len(){
...
   if condition {
      n = 3;
  }
}
```

But in the next iteration `n` is not 3 and the loop continues. Any ideas?

Comment: `n` is not a reference from the iteration, it is just a copied value. even if you had succeed rust wouldn't allow this to prevent concurrent modification though.

Comment: I see. How would you suggest doing something like that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`for n in 0..x` assigns to `n` values from 0 up to (but excluding) `x` without taking into account mutations to `n`, if they occur. That's the case in other languages with foreach-style iteration, e.g. in Python with `for n in range(len(vector))`, or in C++20 with `for (auto n: std::views::iota(0, vector.size()))`.

If you need to occasionally return to a previous state, as afforded by C's `for (n = 0; n < x; n++)`, the simplest option is to just code the C-style loop:

```
let mut n = 0;
while n < vector.len() {
    ...
    if condition {
        n = 3;
        continue;
    }
    n += 1;
}
```

The downside is that `n += 1` is buried at the end of the loop, so that a `continue` that just wants to keep looping (without resetting the loop counter) would actually fail to increment `n`. If that bothers you (and it'd bother me), you can switch to a slightly different foreach-based implementation, where the range is explicit. Instead of with `for`, you loop over the range with `while let`. That gives you the robustness of foreach while allowing you to modify the range you're looping over from inside the loop:

```
let mut range = 0..vector.len();
while let Some(n) = range.next() {
    ...
    if condition {
        range = 3..vector.len();
    }
}
```

Note that your original code evaluated `vector.len()` only once. The C-style loop checks it every time, and this last example also checks it when `condition` is true. If you change the size of the vector, you should probably accompany `vector.push(...)` by `range = n..vector.len()` to correct the upper bound.